# Maintaining Relationships After Termination

Tags: employer-relations, termination

What, in general, is the best protocol to maintain relationships with former colleagues/bosses when you are terminated? Can you still be friends and ask for good recommendations from them? Or should you just forget about them entirely and only have the HR department of the company provide neutral references?

**Added**: The insinuation/connotation was that I was fired,  but technically it was a layoff because I got a severance.

Comment: professional or personal relationships? Leaving a job does not mean you stop being friends with the ones you considered so

Comment: Were you laid off or fired?  That can matter, at least in the asking for references.

Comment: That depends largely or entirely on how well you got along and how much friction your termination caused between you (if any). There isn't a general rule here.

Comment: I was a remote worker and laid off due to a back to the office initiative. I made sure everyone knew the circumstances. I still asked some of my close colleagues for a reference. It depends on if you had a good relationship with your colleagues or not.

Answer (score 1):

Treat them as you would if you left in any other circumstances however be prepared if they don’t reciprocate.

You clearly were not let go in the best circumstances however I would treat this as their judgement of your contribution to the company and not a personal judgement. Contact people as you would if you resigned. If you were friends with people you can still be friends, if a former colleague is a useful contact then feel free to contact her.

Some people may feel awkward about keeping in touch with you. If this is the case don’t force the issue, just let the contact go. Don't judge them negatively for this, you don't know their reasons.

Depending you your history at the company former co-workers and managers may feel reluctant in providing you a reference or making introductions on your behalf. This may because of guidance they received from the company. It may be because they have some qualms about you professionally. This doesn’t mean you can stay in contact as friends or potentially part of your business network in other contexts. Obviously, if you ask people for a reference you need to carefully think about what people may say about you.

Answer (score 1):

I still go for beers every once in a while with a guy who was my boss 8 years ago. Every time, my wife says "didn't he fire you?" as if that would be a reason not to go for a drink with him.

So, stay friends with the people you want to still be friends with. And if they liked your work and let you go because they couldn't afford to pay you any more, then by all means ask them for a reference.